# Why do I see a double leading slash in the url received by (node) express when using an nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running running nginx v1.18.0 (Ubuntu) and node v16.5.0, on Ubuntu 20.04.

Using a minimal test nodejs / express app:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3030

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('\n\n=================================\nRunning test app.js:', req.url)
  next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Node: Hello World!')
})

app.get('/banana', (req, res) => {
  res.send('We have no bananas...')
})

app.get((req, res) => {
  res.send('test app: path not found!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I have set up the nginx config including this location block:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /test {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3030/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

Now if I navigate to http://server/test I get the expected message "Node: Hello world".  But if I try http://server/test/banana I instead get "Cannot GET //banana", and my console logging shows request.url is set to "//banana".  Can anyone explain why I get the double leading slash, and how I might eliminate it?

I have also tried including "merge_slashes on;" in the config (as well as "merge_slashes off;").

I have been careful to restart nginx each time I modify the config.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Thanks.
Brian

Answer (score 1):

I am using Webmin as my control panel.  So I've eventually realised that the Webmin nginx "Update Servers" button does NOT (or not always perhaps?) apply my configuration changes, so most of the solutions I was trying were not actually having any effect.  I am now using "systemctl reload nginx" which does actually apply config changes, and my double-slash problem has gone.  I can no longer tell what actually caused it in the first place.  I hope this helps others.

Comment: ..or I could have clicked Webmin "Apply Changes" like it tells you to.  Doh!